# Finding string in HTML file?

Tags: python, html

Python noob here. I'm trying to print lines that contain a substring in an HTML file with Python. I know that the string is in the file because when I ctrl+f the string I'm searching for in the html file I find it. However when I run my code it doesn't print the desired result. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
import requests
import datetime


from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

now =datetime.datetime.now()

cmonth = now.month
cday = now.day
cyear = now.year
find = 'boxscores/201'


url = 'http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/index.cgi?lid=header_dateoutput&month={0}&day=17&year={2}'.format(cmonth,cday,cyear)
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
print html

for line in html:
    if find in line:
        print line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the requests package response.content is a string, so you should search like this:

```
if find in html:
    # do something
```

By iterating over response.content with

`for line in html`

you are iterating over the individual characters in the string, not lines.

Answer (score 2):

As snakecharmerb said, by using

```
for line in html :
```

you iterate over the characters of html when it's a string, not the lines. But you can use

```
for line in html.split("\n") :
```

to iterate over the lines.

Comment: Addition to both answers. 
response.content is in bytes. You have to use response.text to have string and do .split("\n")